# Why do I get error when trying to start rails console

Tags: ruby

```
$ rails c

Running via Spring preloader in process 3921
/Users/liangshihao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require': dlopen(/Users/liangshihao/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/readline.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/liangshihao/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/readline.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/liangshihao/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/readline.bundle
    from /Users/liangshihao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /Users/liangshihao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/liangshihao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/liangshihao/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/completion.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/liangshihao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/liangshihao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /Users/liangshihao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/liangshihao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/liangshihao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/liangshihao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/liangshihao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /Users/liangshihao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/liangshihao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/liangshihao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:138:in `require_command!'
    from /Users/liangshihao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /Users/liangshihao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/liangshihao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/liangshihao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/liangshihao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /Users/liangshihao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/liangshihao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/liangshihao/railsbridge/suggestotron/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/liangshihao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /Users/liangshihao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
    from /Users/liangshihao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/liangshihao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /Users/liangshihao/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/liangshihao/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: Possibly related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39823011/return-to-readline-version-6-x-in-homebrew-to-fix-postgresql

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16756287/cannot-execute-rails-console-due-to-an-error-with-readline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've updated readline, then you may need to recompile ruby. If you're using rbenv, try uninstalling this version of ruby and reinstalling it.